# configure virtualbox vms to use proxy settings of host

Tags: linux, proxy, virtualbox

I have about 6 VMs for testing purpose in Virtualbox. We have a proxy at work and I do not have a proxy at home. so I switch the settings now and then to get internet inside the VMs. But there has to be a way that the VMs adapt the system settings of my host, or am I wrong? Google didn't help quite good yet. I just found an article about a Microsoft loop back interface, but nothing for Linux. By the way I use Linux just since October, so I am fairly new with this operation system

Some system details:
Host:

- arch-Linux with gnome shell and virtualbox 5.0.12

Guests:

- Ubuntu, win7, win8, centos6 with nat bridge for internet purpose and host-only adapter for internal network

Anybody experience in the matter who can help me?

Comment: Any clue on that? I am having the same issue.

Comment: not yet, I still hope the question to be answered at some stage :)

Comment: Any progress about this issue? I'm hoping to make Linux guest use host proxy setting directly

Comment: Firstly this isn't really a programming question; secondly it's not possible to answer w/o knowing how your machine picks up the proxy when/while at work.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problems you had. I wanted to configure VM's over a corporate proxy. Googling did not help me either. After lots of trials and errors, i finally managed to connect to the internet.

What i did is to configure proxy settings in Guest OS.

I am using ubuntu as Guest OS and its easy to configure the proxy settings as follows:

```
sudo gedit /etc/apt/apt.conf
```

It opens the following file:

```
Acquire::http::Proxy "http://username:pass@myProxyAddress:port/";
Acquire::https::Proxy "https://username:pass@myProxyAddress:port/";
Acquire::ftp::Proxy "ftp://username:pass@myProxyAddress:port/";
Acquire::socks::Proxy "socks://username:pass@myProxyAddress:port/";
```

And you should change the *username*, *pass*, *myProxyAddress* and *port* with your own information. It should be good to go. Some apps like FireFox may still not be able to work so you can configure them manually.

I have done this in Ubuntu but it theoretically work for all linux systems. I don't how to configure system wide proxy for windows or would it solve the problem but it should also work for it.

Hope it helps.

ps: Virtual Host Adapter was blocking my Host OS (Windows). You can either bridge or disable the network adapter so that Host and Guest OS can connect to the internet.

Comment: That is the way I am currently using, as I wrote above. but I have to switch the settings of all 6 VMs everytime I want to use them without a proxy and I am looking for a better way to do that, not to get internet out of the VMs...

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. I tested it on CentOS with NAT model.

`192.168.217.1` is gateway address, and `port` is proxy port in host.

```
export ALL_PROXY=http://192.168.217.1:port
```

Please check you have allow LAN connection to your proxy.